# Is it that time of the year already?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> Strengthen your armies against me, my time is now here.
> I am the enemy you can't see, I'll fill you with fear.
>
> Carried by those careless, ignorant, and weak.
> Keep you captive fairless, suffering that's bleak.
>
> Now don't be afraid, I am mostly innocuous.
> Except when my past is weighed, I may be the apocalypse.
>
> Suffer yourselves to be pricked, lest I come at you like a swift kick.
> So that you may not be picked, when I'm thrown at you like a brick.

What am I?

Comment: What about changing 'what am I' in : 'follow the way- go and die- or now say - what am I- and why ?'

Comment: @NaeemShaikh aren't you supposed to hide spoilers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> Flu Season

Strengthen your armies against me, my time is now here.

> Strengthen your immune system.

I am the enemy you can't see, I'll fill you with fear.

> Don't get sick.

Carried by those careless, ignorant, and weak.

> When those people sneeze without covering their nose.

Keep you captive fairless, suffering that's bleak.

> Sniffle-sniffle

Now don't be afraid, I am mostly innocuous.

> Maybe a little cold.

Except when my past is weighed, I may be the apocalypse.

> Last year 80,000 people died. Horrible.

Suffer yourselves to be pricked, lest I come at you like a swift kick.

> The umm flu shot.

So that you may not be picked, when I'm thrown at you like a brick.

> You may get sick without the shot but you can still get sick with one.

Title

> Time of year = flu season

Acrostic

> Sickness.

Comment: you should not be allowed to read the puzzle untill others have a 10 min headstart :(

Comment: Well, I figured this one may be a little easy. Still, nicely done.

Comment: Great answer! _sniffle-sniffle_ :D (On a side note, I hope this doesn’t reflect Joe-You-Know’s current state.....)

Comment: @El-Guest, can't shake a stupid dry cough, but other than that, I'm okay.

Comment: Good to hear, @Joe-You-Know! Keep up the fluids/water!! (I’m currently in the same state myself so passing along the wisdom of others much smarter than me!)